# Add column to pd.df based on complicated condition

Tags: pandas, numpy, boolean, python-3.6

I have two df looking like this:

```
In [500]: df1.iloc[67:100]
Out[500]: 
        Expiry       K Type     close
107 2018-01-26  123.00    C  0.406250
108 2018-01-26  124.00    C  0.062500
109 2018-01-26  125.00    C  0.015625
112 2018-01-26  121.50    C  1.640625
121 2018-02-23  123.50    C  0.406250
124 2018-02-23  127.50    C  0.015625
127 2018-02-23  124.50    C  0.140625
130 2018-02-23  125.50    C  0.046875
144 2018-05-25  120.00    C  3.156250
145 2018-05-25  121.00    C  2.203125
146 2018-05-25  122.00    C  1.328125
147 2018-02-23  123.00    C  0.640625
148 2018-02-23  124.00    C  0.234375
152 2018-02-23  121.50    C  1.750000
156 2018-02-23  126.50    C  0.015625
158 2018-02-23  122.50    C  0.953125
160 2018-03-23  123.25    P  0.484375
161 2018-03-23  123.50    P  0.625000
162 2018-03-23  123.75    P  0.796875
163 2018-03-23  127.25    P  4.125000
164 2018-03-23  127.50    P  4.375000

In [501]: df2
Out[501]: 
                              F       Symbol
Expiry                                      
2018-03-20 12:00:00  123.125000  ZN   MAR 18
2018-06-20 12:00:00  122.734375  ZN   JUN 18
2018-09-19 12:00:00  122.265625  ZN   SEP 18
```

am looking to add a column with 'F' (from df2) to df1 based on the following function:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
def find_F(df1_expiry):
    F = df2.loc[(df2.index > df1_expiry + MonthEnd(1)) &
             (df2.index < df1_expiry + MonthEnd(4))].F
    return F
```

Apply does the trick:

```
df['F'] = df1['Expiry'].apply(find_F)
```

just not sure this is the best way.

Expected Output:

```
        Expiry       K Type     close  F
107 2018-01-26  123.00    C  0.406250  123.125000 
108 2018-01-26  124.00    C  0.062500  123.125000 
109 2018-01-26  125.00    C  0.015625  123.125000 
112 2018-01-26  121.50    C  1.640625  123.125000 
121 2018-02-23  123.50    C  0.406250  123.125000 
124 2018-02-23  127.50    C  0.015625  123.125000 
127 2018-02-23  124.50    C  0.140625  123.125000 
130 2018-02-23  125.50    C  0.046875  123.125000 
144 2018-05-25  120.00    C  3.156250  122.734375
145 2018-05-25  121.00    C  2.203125  122.734375
146 2018-05-25  122.00    C  1.328125  122.734375
147 2018-02-23  123.00    C  0.640625  122.734375
148 2018-02-23  124.00    C  0.234375  122.734375
152 2018-06-22  121.50    C  1.750000  122.265625
156 2018-06-22  126.50    C  0.015625  122.265625
158 2018-02-23  122.50    C  0.953125  122.734375
160 2018-03-23  123.25    P  0.484375  122.734375
161 2018-03-23  123.50    P  0.625000  122.734375
162 2018-03-23  123.75    P  0.796875  122.734375
163 2018-03-23  127.25    P  4.125000  122.734375
164 2018-03-23  127.50    P  4.375000  122.734375
```

Am looking for the most effect way to this. Grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: What is `print (df2.loc[(df2.index > df1['Expiry'] + relativedelta(day=1, months=1)) & 
             (df2.index < df1['Expiry'] + relativedelta(day=31,months=6))].F.head())` ?

Comment: But if same length of both DataFrames, `df1['F'] = df2.loc[(df2.index > df1['Expiry'] + relativedelta(day=1, months=1)) & 
             (df2.index < df1['Expiry'] + relativedelta(day=31,months=6)), 'F'].values` should working

Comment: they are not same length. df2 has 3 rows while df1 has >400 rows.

Comment: print (df2.loc[(df2.index > df1['Expiry'] + relativedelta(day=1, months=1)) & (df2.index < df1['Expiry'] + relativedelta(day=31,months=6))].F.head())
gives:
TypeError: incompatible type [object] for a datetime/timedelta operation

Comment: OK, so what is `print (df2)` ?

Comment: both there already. see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If input 2 DataFrames first step is create one (e.g. by cross join) and then filter:

```
df = pd.merge(df1.assign(A=1), df2.reset_index().assign(A=1)[['A','Expiry','F']], on='A')
mask = (df['Expiry_y'] > df['Expiry_x'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(day=1, months=1)) & \
       (df['Expiry_y'] < df['Expiry_x'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(day=31,months=6))

df = df[mask]
print (df.head())
    Expiry_x      K Type     close  A            Expiry_y           F
0 2018-01-26  123.0    C  0.406250  1 2018-03-20 12:00:00  123.125000
1 2018-01-26  123.0    C  0.406250  1 2018-06-20 12:00:00  122.734375
3 2018-01-26  124.0    C  0.062500  1 2018-03-20 12:00:00  123.125000
4 2018-01-26  124.0    C  0.062500  1 2018-06-20 12:00:00  122.734375
6 2018-01-26  125.0    C  0.015625  1 2018-03-20 12:00:00  123.125000
```

EDIT:

You can use:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
def find_F(df1):
    F = df2.loc[(df2.index > df1 + MonthEnd(1)) &
             (df2.index < df1 + MonthEnd(4)), 'F']
    return F.values[0]

df1['F'] = df1['Expiry'].apply(find_F)
print (df1)
        Expiry       K Type     close           F
107 2018-01-26  123.00    C  0.406250  123.125000
108 2018-01-26  124.00    C  0.062500  123.125000
109 2018-01-26  125.00    C  0.015625  123.125000
112 2018-01-26  121.50    C  1.640625  123.125000
121 2018-02-23  123.50    C  0.406250  123.125000
124 2018-02-23  127.50    C  0.015625  123.125000
127 2018-02-23  124.50    C  0.140625  123.125000
130 2018-02-23  125.50    C  0.046875  123.125000
144 2018-05-25  120.00    C  3.156250  122.734375
145 2018-05-25  121.00    C  2.203125  122.734375
146 2018-05-25  122.00    C  1.328125  122.734375
147 2018-02-23  123.00    C  0.640625  123.125000
148 2018-02-23  124.00    C  0.234375  123.125000
152 2018-02-23  121.50    C  1.750000  123.125000
156 2018-02-23  126.50    C  0.015625  123.125000
158 2018-02-23  122.50    C  0.953125  123.125000
160 2018-03-23  123.25    P  0.484375  122.734375
161 2018-03-23  123.50    P  0.625000  122.734375
162 2018-03-23  123.75    P  0.796875  122.734375
163 2018-03-23  127.25    P  4.125000  122.734375
164 2018-03-23  127.50    P  4.375000  122.734375
```

Or:

```
df = pd.merge(df1.assign(A=1), 
              df2.reset_index().assign(A=1)[['A','Expiry','F']], on='A')
mask = (df['Expiry_y'] > df['Expiry_x'] + MonthEnd(1)) & \
       (df['Expiry_y'] < df['Expiry_x'] + MonthEnd(4))

df = df[mask].drop('Expiry_y', 1)
print (df)
     Expiry_x       K Type     close  A           F
0  2018-01-26  123.00    C  0.406250  1  123.125000
3  2018-01-26  124.00    C  0.062500  1  123.125000
6  2018-01-26  125.00    C  0.015625  1  123.125000
9  2018-01-26  121.50    C  1.640625  1  123.125000
12 2018-02-23  123.50    C  0.406250  1  123.125000
15 2018-02-23  127.50    C  0.015625  1  123.125000
18 2018-02-23  124.50    C  0.140625  1  123.125000
21 2018-02-23  125.50    C  0.046875  1  123.125000
25 2018-05-25  120.00    C  3.156250  1  122.734375
28 2018-05-25  121.00    C  2.203125  1  122.734375
31 2018-05-25  122.00    C  1.328125  1  122.734375
33 2018-02-23  123.00    C  0.640625  1  123.125000
36 2018-02-23  124.00    C  0.234375  1  123.125000
39 2018-02-23  121.50    C  1.750000  1  123.125000
42 2018-02-23  126.50    C  0.015625  1  123.125000
45 2018-02-23  122.50    C  0.953125  1  123.125000
49 2018-03-23  123.25    P  0.484375  1  122.734375
52 2018-03-23  123.50    P  0.625000  1  122.734375
55 2018-03-23  123.75    P  0.796875  1  122.734375
58 2018-03-23  127.25    P  4.125000  1  122.734375
61 2018-03-23  127.50    P  4.375000  1  122.734375
```

**Timings**:

There is no very big difference, so if use only `400` rows DataFrame timings are good for both solutions.

If larger data, timings should be different, but not tested.

```
In [177]: %%timeit
     ...: from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
     ...: def find_F(df1):
     ...:     F = df2.loc[(df2.index > df1 + MonthEnd(1)) &
     ...:              (df2.index < df1 + MonthEnd(4)), 'F']
     ...:     return F.values[0]
     ...: 
     ...: df1['F'] = df1['Expiry'].apply(find_F)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 15.7 ms per loop

In [178]: %%timeit
     ...: df = pd.merge(df1.assign(A=1), df2.reset_index().assign(A=1)[['A','Expiry','F']], on='A')
     ...: mask = (df['Expiry_y'] > df['Expiry_x'] + MonthEnd(1)) & \
     ...:        (df['Expiry_y'] < df['Expiry_x'] + MonthEnd(4))
     ...: 
     ...: df = df[mask].drop('Expiry_y', 1)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 9.48 ms per loop
```

Comment: Super, glad can help!

Comment: So there is some problem?

Comment: need to select only one F per two in df1. amended the question.
Sorry about this. only realised today. probably a little hungover yday

Comment: No problem. So what is `opt_exp` in your function? And mainly what is expected output?

Comment: oops. changed it. should be obv now. Basically it should always select one F based on the df.Expiry. The function should do that.

Comment: Yes, but problem is you need join both DataFrames first, so what is expected output?

Comment: how about loop or apply to create the column? what u reckon is best?

Comment: loops in pandas are obviously not nice, because slow :(

Comment: df1 has about 400 rows and in the above example it should always add the first row F

Comment: Yes, it is hard to answer without expected output. Can you add some [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Thank you very much.